# Choosing the second to last value in Impala/HIVE/SQL

Tags: sql, hive, impala

I would like to get the second to last item of a list in Impala. Is there a function/method that would return (min+1)(x)?

Example table:

```
foo   bar
 1     3
 2     5
 3     6
 4     2
 5     8
```

The function

```
SELECT MIN(bar) FROM example
```

will return

```
bar
 2
```

I would like to select instead the second to last value from the list of numerical values in bar:

```
SELECT SECONDTOLAST(bar) FROM example
```

returning

```
bar
 3
```

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  For instance, I am not aware what "list" means in a SQL context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `row_number()` function :

```
select t.bar
from (select *, row_number() over (order by bar) as seq
      from table
     ) t
where seq = 2; -- Get the second last bar
```